# I am unable to visit the list of WebElements one by one using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to search a subject on amazon and then go on the given list of books given one by one to perform a specific action. I have done the following:

```
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("Operating System Books");
        driver.findElement(By.className("nav-input")).click();
        links = driver.findElements(By.className("s-access-detail-page")); //try to cache this
        for(WebElement link : links) {
              //System.out.println(String.format(link.getAttribute("href"))); //prints
              link.click();
              //extract reviews and one by one forward to semantic analysis 
              driver.navigate().back();
          }
        }
```

However, this one goes to first link and then back to page of list. The program then terminates with following error: 
**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document**

Comment: It is completely normal that you would have this exception: `StaleElement` means that element you are trying to refer to is no longer on the active browser window. Considering that you have navigated to some other page and then navigated back, no element from previous page should be active anymore. You'd either have to redo your searches or open link in new window, so your original window is still intact in another browser tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StaleElementReferenceException` when a `webElement` is no longer attached to DOM, this generally happens when you navigate away from a webpage and then after navigating back to the original page you try to use `WebElements` which were stored or captured earlier.

In order to avoid this Exception you need to identify previously captured elements once again, in your case your code should be like below:

```
List <WebElement>links = driver.findElements(By.className("s-access-detail-page")); //try to cache this

        for(int i=0; i< links.size(); i++) {

             List <WebElement> refLinks = driver.findElements(By.className("s-access-detail-page"));

             refLinks.get(i).click();

             driver.navigate().back();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error because** : The element you are referring is no longer present in active page. Try this code :

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys(
            "Operating System Books");
    driver.findElement(By.className("nav-input")).click();
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By
            .className("s-access-detail-page"));

    for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {

        List<WebElement> allLink = driver.findElements(By
                .className("s-access-detail-page"));

        allLink.get(i).click();



        driver.navigate().back();

    }


}
```